# data-id attribute using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I'm using jQuery. I need to get the `data-id` of the clicked item and pass it to a webservice. How do I get the `data-id` attribute?

My HTML looks like this:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="onselectedCategory" data-id="12"><a href="javascript:;;">12</a></li>
    <li class="onselectedCategory" data-id="23"><a href="javascript:;;">23</a></li>
    <li class="onselectedCategory" data-id="34"><a href="javascript:;;">34</a></li>
    <li class="onselectedCategory" data-id="45"><a href="javascript:;;">45</a></li>
    <li class="onselectedCategory" data-id="56"><a href="javascript:;;">56</a></li>
</ul>
```

And my JavaScript looks like this:

```js
events{
      "click li.onselectedCategory": "selectCategory"
    }

selectCategory: function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
        var _selectedValue = $(this).data('id'); 
        alert("Selected Value : "+_selectedValue);
    },
```

Comment: just remove the sharp.

Comment: Don't you search first to get id and class in jQuery

Comment: Are you using backbone.js?

Comment: yes, we are using backbone.js, backbone-maronette and underscore.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `#data-id` to `data-id`

```
 $(".onselectedCategory").click(function(){ 
   alert($(this).attr("data-id")); 
 })
```

**Edit for backbone**

```
 selectCategory: function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var selectedValue = "";
        if($(e.target).is('li')) {
            selectedValue =$(e.target).attr('data-id');
        } else {
           selectedValue =$(e.target).parent().attr('data-id');
        }       
        alert("Selected Value : "+ selectedValue);
    },
```

Comment: still i am getting the alert value is "Undefined".

Comment: @user3652322 please check now

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$(".onselectedCategory").click(function(){ 
    alert($(this).data("id")); 
});
```

`onselectedCategory` is a class, therefor you need to reference it with a `.` and not with the `#` which is used for ids.

Answer (score 0):

The `onselectedCategory` class must be within the label `<a>`

```
<li><a class="onselectedCategory" data-id="12" bla,bla,bla...</li>

$(".onselectedCategory").click(function(){ alert($(this).data("id")); });
```